# mysql trigger. How to right change value in inseriting row if it's null (default)

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table lbs_records, with fields:

```
taken TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
expected TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
```

and I have trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_records_correct $$
CREATE TRIGGER trig_records_correct BEFORE INSERT ON lbs_records
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF ( NEW.expected IS NULL ) THEN
    SET NEW.expected = adddate( NEW.taken, ( SELECT lbs_books.`4home_ondays`
      FROM lbs_books WHERE lbs_books.id = NEW.book_id ) );
  END IF;
  UPDATE lbs_books
  SET lbs_books.in_stock = lbs_books.in_stock -1
  WHERE lbs_books.id = NEW.book_id;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

When I try to insert row in this table, my trigger only change (decrease) value in lbs_books.in_stock for row with id = NEW.book_id. But it don't change field 'expected' in row that inserts now. And after insert row, 'expected' field is null.

> 1. Am I right that when trigger start working for query `INSERT INTO
>      lbs_records (user_id, book_id) VALUES (5,1);`, it get row also with fields
>      'taken':'curr datetime', 'expected':'null'?
> 2. Why after to insert row, this row contains field 'expected' that even after trigger's work is null?

Comment: Can you give some sample data from lbs_books (especially the 4home_ondays values)

Comment: @NigelRen, yes ofc [screenshot](http://take.ms/WwJyA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using MySQL before insert triggers, the default values of columns are not set, so either change the select to add the default in again...

```
SET NEW.expected = adddate( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), ( SELECT lbs_books.`4home_ondays`
      FROM lbs_books WHERE lbs_books.id = NEW.book_id ) );
```

Or fetch the value before hand...

```
SET NEW.taken = DEFAULT(lbs_books.taken)
```

Or the longer way...

```
   SELECT COLUMN_DEFAULT INTO @def
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
   WHERE
     table_schema = 'database_name'
     AND table_name = 'lbs_books'
     AND column_name = 'taken';
   SET NEW.taken = @def;
```

Comment: Did u mean that field 'taken' not contain datetime if query has been started with default value for this field? So then what value contain this field? Null?